# Unity 3D: What could cause the rotation gizmo to be offset from the gameobject center?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, position

I placed my gameobject at 0, 0, 0 in world space, but when I select the position or rotate tools, the gizmos are not at 0, 0, 0, but are off-center. What could cause the rotation gizmo to be offset from the gameobject center?

Answer (score 2):

Ah ha! I've found it!

For others who might have the same problem in the future: At the top of the Unity editor, there are buttons to put gizmos at either "local" or "pivot". These can change the location of the gizmo relative to either the individual object or the object and its children collectively. I must have accidentally clicked one of these.

Comment: So, "local" switches to "world" and alters the alignment of the translation and rotation gizmos to local- or world-space.  "pivot" switches with "centre" and determines the point around which rotations occur (geometry 'centre' or geometry 'origin', or zero-point).  When you use ```transform.rotate()```, this rotates around 'pivot'.

Comment: Of note, if you have multiple objects selected, rotating around 'pivot' rotates the objects individually, but rotating around 'centre' rotates them collecively around the groups' centre.